# MFC InValRect or Post or Send msg to ChildView from background thread

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to cause an OnPaint event to my MFC ChileView window from a background thread.
I am fine with respect to the background thread and its chatter with the Comm port.
But I am stuck with respect to involving an OnPaint to my foreground Window to paint the data from the Comm port. I guess I need to get the ChileView handle/CWnd during `CChildView::PreSubclassWindow()` or similar then do a InValRect or the like but am stuck, can someone help please?

Comment: You need to add some appropriate message to mfc's message queue – I'd assume they use a Windows message queue for (but not putting my hand in fire for) – if so, then you should have a look at [`PostMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea) function of windows API. Still, mfc is a pretty inconvenient and maybe even outdated library. There are many other ones that are far more convenient to use. You might consult your favourite search engine for `gui framework C++`, that should give you plenty of results...

Comment: What's the question exactly? How to get the view's CWnd* pointer or handle? What's the preferred method of invalidating/updating the window? Did you try calling `InvalidateRect()` (from the worker thread)? Is it OK to paint the entire client area, or it would be best to paint a portion of it instead? Does it need to be synchronous (be updated immediately) or not? Etc, etc...

Comment: constantine georgiou many thanks for the reply.
The application is  a MFC  app with a CChildView that i draw some graphics in but the app also has a modeless dialog that i use to control the background thread. So if issue an InvalidateRect does it go to the diaglog or the CChildView . Hence how do i get the handle/CWnd whatever of the CChildView and send a WM_PAIN to it from the background thread please?

Comment: [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) takes an `HWND` argument. It operates on that window. The core issue here probably is, that you do not understand the anatomy of a Windows application. MFC makes this **substantially** harder to learn.

Comment: So, how do you associate the worker thread to the document or view? In other words, where does the worker thread store the data it receives? Are they global? In this case I would rather assume that it's a SDI application. An SDI application instantiates exactly one document object at runtime (not 0 or >1), so it would be absolutely acceptable to declare/define a gloabal pointer to your view and the modeless dialog. Otherwise you need a reference from the thread to the document/view (stored in a c++ thread object or in thread-local storage, if you prefer a WinAPI-level implementation).

Comment: Also, you should never send/post `WM_PAINT` messages yourself, you should instead invalidate a part or the whole client area of a window, it will then receive a `WM_PAINT` message from the system. If you want the update to be performed immediately you can call `UpdateWindow()`. Or bypass the invalidate/update mechanism, using `GetDC()/ReleaseDC()` to "draw" specific parts of the window.

Comment: Thanks all for help, this works 
ChildViewhWnd = GetSafeHwnd();
InvalidateRect( ChildViewhWnd ,  0 , 0 );
imk